# How to parse through .csv using conditional statements

Tags: python, csv, error-handling

I'm having trouble having with error handling for sys.argv. Basicially I want my code to check if I've entered wrong .csv file (A csv file that doesn't actually exist in that directory) as an argument.

I've tried using sys.argv and try/else for error handling

For example the correct argument is **python3 csvfind.py csvSample.csv**, however lets say I enter a .csv file that doesn't exist, so: **python3 csvfind.py csvSample2.csv**. I want my code to print('Error! File Not Found!') but instead I keep getting the ('No CSV File has been specified') which should only output when I don't use any csv file as an argument. I can't get thi to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
try:

    # check if an CSV file has been specified
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise FileNotFoundError('No CSV File has been specified!')

    else:
        csv_file = sys.argv[1]
        file = open(csv_file, 'r')
        ld = load_data(csv_file)
        print("Source File: " + str(sys.argv[1]))
       

except ValueError:
    print('Error! - File Not Found!')


except TypeError:
    print('Error! - File Not Found!')



except FileNotFoundError:
    print('No CSV File has been specified!')`
```

Input:

```
python3 csvfind.py csvSample2.csv
```

Expected Output:

```
Error! - File Not Found!
```

Actual Output:

```
No CSV File has been specified
```

Comment: python3 is the ```0`th```.  ```netparse.py``` is the ```st``` and csvsample2.csv is the ```2nd```.

Comment: You'll need to iterate over your arguments somewhere, somehow, presumably with `for`. Consider using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to help you structure things.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a missing *argument* to generate the error, "No CSV File has been specified!", and that you want a missing *file* to generate the error, "Error! - File Not Found!".  While I can point out the problem, I don't know the bigger picture so I don't know exactly what to recommend.  I'll still try at the bottom, though.

The problem is: your custom `raise FileNotFoundError("No CSV File...")` and `open(csv_file, 'r')` raise the same exception: FileNotFoundError.

`open(...)` raises that exception when you give it a file that doesn't exist. So, for the simple code you've shown, you'll probably never raise an actual ValueError that will catch and print "Error! - File Not Found!".

To help illustrate this, I've reduced your program to the following:

- test args length, and throw `FileNotFourndError` if the value of sys.argv is less than 2; or...
- try to open 2nd argument as a file then print that argument

I've removed all exception handling so we can see excatly what exceptions the program generates and where they come from:

```py
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    raise FileNotFoundError("No CSV File has been specified!")

csv_file = sys.argv[1]
file = open(csv_file, "r")
print("Source File: " + str(sys.argv[1]))
```

I only have one CSV in my test directory, input1.csv.  When I run the command the following three different ways, I get:

- With a real file:

  ```
  python3 main.py input1.csv

  Source File: input1.csv
  ```
- With a fake file:

  ```
  python3 main.py input2.csv

    File "/Users/zyoung/develop/StackOverflow/main.py", line 8, in <module>
      file = open(csv_file, "r")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input2.csv'
  ```
- Without the file argument:

  ```
  python3 main.py

    File "/Users/zyoung/develop/StackOverflow/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      raise FileNotFoundError("No CSV File has been specified!")
  FileNotFoundError: No CSV File has been specified!
  ```

We can now clearly see that both the explicit raise and the implicit raise in open(...) are both FileNotFoundErrors, and this is why you get the same error for the two different conditions you've tried to establish.

What to do about it?

Again, I don't know exactly what the bigger picture of your program is, so I'm going to assume you're writing a command-line utility to do something with CSVs. I've written about a hundred of these over the years and I've developed the practice/style of *guarding* against the few, obvious, and know-ably bad preconditions that are likely to crop up, like you did:

1. No CSV file specified
2. Non-existent CSV file specified

```py
import csv
import os
import sys

# Deal with obvious and expected problems up-front
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("usage: program.py CSV_FILE", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

fname = sys.argv[1]

if not os.path.exists(fname):
    print(f"could not find CSV {fname}", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

# Try to proceed, giving Python as much room to tell us what
# problems actually happened
data = []
try:
    with open(fname, "r", newline="") as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        data = list(reader)
    print(f"Source File: {fname}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"error: could not load CSV {fname}: {e}", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

# Do stuff with data...
```

I try to avoid defining too many exceptions in the beginning.  I just go with the blanket `except Exception as e`, and print it.  Over time, I may start to see common problems I run into, and only then do I start writing special error handling.